# how to set a key event after decimal point or before decimal point value in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

The requirements are:

1. the default value of text box will be 0.00 so I set it in property.
2. if the value entered is 52.55 in the text box, and if the user deletes 55 after ., it should change to 00 i.e 52.00
3. same way if user deleting 52 using backspace or delete, it should become 0.55 for the user to update.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Show or tell us what have you tried and what concrete problem do you have as SO is not "write me some code" portal.

Comment: What method you are used please tell us. That will helps us to understand your problem. So that we can try to give some answer.

Comment: Set .Text property of your textbox in Constructor at 0.00 or do this in the designer(your choice), use the OnTextChanged event of the textbox and handle the 2 remaining points there, this is very easy to implement.